# deploy phpBB on openshift

Tags: php, openshift, phpbb

I'm in a trouble trying to install phpBB on openshift.
I have created a php5.3 cartridge with PostgreSQL: I unpack phpbb on a folder of my app, I push the change, then I run the installation form the browser.
The forum installation is successful.

In the end I need to delete the "install" folder in order to enable the forum.
I tried it on my standalone wampp server and it works.
So I delete it in my repo, and I commit and push the change.
When the app restarts it automatically tries to go back to the installation: everything is broken.
It seems the push breaks the configuration on the server side.

I also have tried to change the name of the directory using ssh connection, and move the install directory name: this is uneffective.
What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you deploy the phpBB package as downloaded from official website app the files will go on app-deployments with are not persistent on git changes and can not be pull to local. You can try using the OpenShift quickdeply version of phpBB (https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/phpbb-example) that deploys the files to app-root/data (I think :S) and this reamins untouched on git changes.

Comment: This looks more like a link to an answer; please post any relevant code/documentation here since links can change and this answer would become irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The "install" folder is at app-root/runtime/repo/php